# Why are variables set inside (...) lost afterwards in bash?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

```
$ p="pineapple" ; echo $p
pineapple
$ (p="peach" ; echo $p)
peach
$ echo $p
pineapple
```

Why does the shell doesn't display peach since it was initialized last ? Does the parentheses play a role in this result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what the parenthesis are for in Bourne-like and csh-like shells: introduce a sub-shell environment (which in most shells including `bash` is implemented by forking a child process) where modifications are confined in.

Any change to the shell state within that subshell environment whether it's a variable, option, alias, function, redirection, current working directory, signal disposition... is lost (reverted) upon leaving it.

It is very useful to run *only* some commands in a different environment.

For instance:

```
(cd /some/dir && cmd)
```

To run `cmd` in a different directory.

Or in things like:

```
(IFS=:; set -o noglob; ls -l -- $PATH)
```

where we tune the split+glob operator only for that one expansion of `$PATH`.

If you want to group commands without introducing a subshell environment, use the `{` and `}` keywords instead:

```
a=1
{ echo "I'm running in the main shell environemnt"; a=2;}
echo "$a"
(echo "I'm running in a subshell environment"; a=3)
echo "$a"
```

Note the space after a `{` and `;` before `}` as those are keywords made of ordinary characters, while `(` and `)` are special characters in the shell syntax, here used for the `(...)` subshell construct.

Also note that `(...)` is not the only construct that introduces a subshell environment. There's also (in Bourne/Korn-like shells):

- some forms of command substitution: `$(subshell)` or `` `subshell` ``
- process substitution: `<(subshell)`, `>(subshell)`, `=(subshell)`
- pipeline components: `{ subshell; } | othercommand` (not the last component in AT&T ksh or zsh).
- asynchronous command: `{ subshell; } &`
- co-processes: `{ subshell; } |&` or `coproc { subshell; }`

In the POSIX shell grammar, both `{ ...; }` and `(...)` are so called *compound commands*. Both can be assigned to functions. Defining a function as:

```
func() (
  ...
)
```

instead of

```
func() {
  ...
}
```

means that, once invoked, the body of that function is run in a subshell environment which makes it behave more like a script (not the same as it still inherits all the variables, aliases, functions, options... of the caller).

In the `fish` shell, `(...)` is something completely different. It is command substitution, but one that does **not** introduce a subshell environment:

```
fish> set a 1; echo $a (set a 2; echo $a) $a
1 2 2
```

It is similar to the `${ ...; }` form of command substitution of the ksh93 or mksh shells which also don't introduce a subshell environment.